# Android inject firebase firestore with hilt in repository pattern

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, repository, dagger-hilt

I have problem with my project when try add firebaseFirestore in constructor of my repository, "error: cannot find symbol
return DaggerBraziliexApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.builder()"

and with that I can't build the project, how should I proceed with the injection in this case?

Interface

```
interface NewsRepository {
suspend fun fetchNewsFromApi(
    query: String,
    date: String,
    apiKey: String
): Flow<Result<List<NewsModelView>>>
}
```

RepositoryImpl

```
class NewsRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val apiService: NewsService,
private val newsMapper: NewsMapper,
private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore
): NewsRepository {

override suspend fun fetchNewsFromApi(
    query: String,
    date: String,
    apiKey: String
): Flow<Result<List<NewsModelView>>> {
   //TODO Implement API Request
}

private fun saveDataInFirestore(modelView: List<NewsModelView>, date: String) {
    //TODO use firebaseFirestore do save response
}
}
```

Hilt Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

private const val baseUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/"

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("news_api")
fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit{
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideNewsService(@Named("news_api") retrofit: Retrofit): NewsService{
    return retrofit.create(NewsService::class.java)
}

@Provides
@Singleton
    fun provideFirestore() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class RemoteModule {

    @Binds
    @ViewModelScoped
    abstract fun bindRemoteRepository(remoteRepository: NewsRepositoryImpl): NewsRepository
}
```

Comment: Could you add the full error log? You can click on "show error stacktrace" and then post it here. I find this confusing, because I can easily inject my FirebaseFirestore Instance into my repository. Did you maybe forgot a `@Inject` inside your NewsMapper class?

Comment: Please edit your question and add what Andrew already asked for and please also respond with @.